# What constitutes a workspace mapping when creating a new build definition?

Tags: build

We've been using TFS 2015 for a few years. I've got TFS 2018 installed on a test server and am experimenting with it. I want to make a new build definition to a project I have in an TFVC repo, in TFS 2018. So, creating a new definition I have selected the source as TFVC. Next it asks for a Workspace mappings, which I'm not clear as to what that is in this case. It defaults to the team project in the TFS repo, in this case it's $/RodTest. However, I don't want to choose that, because there are several projects within the RodTest team project. Instead I want to only create a build definition for one project named FindNonAscii. So, I figured I could do one of two things:

- $/RodTest/FindNonAscii
- $/RodTest/FindNonAscii/FindNonAscii.sln

Which is the correct mapping I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mappings are recursive. Map the root folder and anything underneath will be downloaded.